# how to save an image from discord using discord bot node js

Tags: node.js, discord.js

So far I've only been able to get text and links from what other people on my discord channel type, but I want to be able to save posted images/gifs. is there any way I can do this through the bot or is it impossible? I'm using discord.js.

Comment: Where are you wanting to save the images / gifs? You mean on your person computer, or on the server hosting your bot, or some other database like firebase?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Images in Discord.js come in the form of [MessageAttachments](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/11.2.0/class/MessageAttachment) via `Message#attachments`. By looping through the amount of attachments, we can retrieve the raw file via [MessageAttachment#attachment](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/11.2.0/class/MessageAttachment?scrollTo=attachment) and the file type using [MessageAttachment#name](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/11.2.0/class/MessageAttachment?scrollTo=name). Then, we use node's [FileSystem](https://nodejs.org/docs/latest-v10.x/api/fs.html) to write the file onto the system. Here's a quick example. This example assumes you already have the message event and the message variable.

```
const fs = require('fs');
msg.attachments.forEach(a => {
    fs.writeFileSync(`./${a.name}`, a.file); // Write the file to the system synchronously.
});
```

Please note that in a real world scenario you should surround the synchronous function with a try/catch statement, for errors.

Also note that, according to the docs, the attachment can be a stream. I have yet to have this happen in the real world, but if it does it might be worth checking if `a` is typeof Stream, and then using fs.createWriteStream and piping the file into it.